# Show that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are regular submanifold

Tags: proof-verification, manifolds

Consider the following subsets of $\mathbb{R^3}$

$1$) $S_1 = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} : x^3+y^3+z^3 = 1\}$

$2$) $S_2 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} : x^3+y^3+z^3 = 1 , x+y+z=0 \}$

I need to show that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are **regular submanifolds** of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

So for $S_1$, I calculated the critical points which can be found either by writing a Jacobian or simply differentiating the function and equating it to $0$. The only critical point is $(0,0,0)$ and since this point doesn't belong to $S_1$, s0 every point of $S_1$ is a regular point and hence $S_1$ is a regular submanifold. Is my approach correct?

However, if I apply the same reasoning for $S_2$, I run into trouble as here the critical point $(0,0,0)$ does lie in $S_2$ and so it can not be a regular submanifold as every point is not a regular point. Am I wrong here?

If I am not right then please help me with the solution!

Comment: It's important to be aware that the theorem you're using says _if_ every point in the zero set of a smooth function is a regular point, _then_ the zero set is a regular submanifold. It does not imply the converse!  (For example, if $f(x,y,z)=z^2$, then every point in $f^{-1}(0)$ is a critical point, and yet the zero set is a regular submanifold.)

Comment: @JackLee So if a zero set is a regular submanifold then it is not necessary that every point in that set is a regular point?

Comment: What he is saying is that you are applying the regular value theorem. And the statement says that if for all $p \in f^{-1}(q)$ the differential $d_pf$ is surjective then f^{-1}(q) is a regular submanifold. The only point in which you found that $d_pf$ is not surjective (or has full rank) is $p = (0,0,0)$ but that point is not in the preimage.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Ok got it!

Comment: @user383517: It's not really an issue in this problem, but you're right: If a zero set is a regular submanifold, then it's not necessarily a regular level set.

Answer (score 1):

For $S_2$, you know that each piece is a submanifold ($x+y+z = 0$ is a plane). Now just show that the intersection of the manifolds (which are the solution sets of) $x^3+y^3+z^3=1,x+y+z = 0$ is transverse and you are done.

Comment: So in general for any such kind of sets (like $S_2$) , we just need to find the points of intersection and apply regular value theorem on them?

Comment: That is what I usually do. To get that the intersection is transverse. Use techniques from multivariable calculus to get a tangent vector for $p$ with respect to the manifold $f^{-1}(1)$ where $f(x,y,z) = x^3+y^3+z^3$. Think gradient vector. Now look at this gradient vector and the normal to the plane $x+y+z = 0$. Once you can say that these vectors aren't parallel, you are done.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood What do you mean by transverse here?

Comment: @Dark_Knight look up transversality. It's a specific kind of intersection between objects.